# Running MPI on ParallelGroup I get a reshape error in default_vector

Tags: openmdao

I have a workflow with a ParallelGroup. I instantiate many times the same Component inside it and pass each a different input.
I am using the option `prob.setup(vector_class=PETScVector, check=False, mode='fwd')` like in the example.
I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workflow.py", line 73, in <module>
    prob.run_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 282, in run_model
    self.final_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 423, in final_setup
    model._final_setup(comm, vector_class, 'full', force_alloc_complex=force_alloc_complex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openmdao/core/system.py", line 787, in _final_setup
    force_alloc_complex=force_alloc_complex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openmdao/core/system.py", line 586, in _get_root_vectors
    ncol=ncol, relevant=rel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openmdao/vectors/vector.py", line 160, in __init__
    self._initialize_views()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openmdao/vectors/default_vector.py", line 320, in _initialize_views
    v.shape = shape
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (4,3)
```

The variable with shape (4,3) is a "global" variable given to the ParallelGroup (by promotion of each of its Components) by an external IndepVarComp.

EDIT: This only happens when the number of nodes allocated is less than the number of Components in the ParallelGroup.

Comment: you probably be using `check=False` when you're getting error msgs. There might be relevant information in the check you need to see

Comment: I see now that if the number of nodes used to run is the same as the number of cases, it runs fine. I thought I could specify the number of processors I wanted to use instead and have OpenMDAO distribute them evenly. But then is when I get the error. Thanks!

Comment: In a future release we'll actually allow what you're describing. But not yet.